# Change DISPLAY to remote host

Tags: shell-script, awk, sed, regular-expression

I would like to replace the IP in $DISPLAY to the remote host IP ($SSH_CLIENT or $SSH_CONNECTION)

```
$(echo $DISPLAY | sed -e "s/^[^:]*\(.*\)/$(echo $SSH_CLIENT | awk '{ print $1}')\1/")
```

I did it above, but I feel like there should be a much shorter way to do this.  I want to embe this into a command line argument for another program so I'd like it as short as possible.

Comment: Why not use the `-X` option of `ssh`?

Comment: if you input and expected output, Then it would be easy to check